# how do we change views in flet ? I get an error -> signal only works in main thread of the main interpreter

Tags: python, flet

Here is the code for the same. I have two functions, one is main and other i named as main2.
How do we change the view from main to main2?

```
import flet
from flet import Checkbox, ElevatedButton, Row,Text, TextField,sleep,Column
from flet import (
    AppBar,
    Icon,
    IconButton,
    Page,
    PopupMenuButton,
    PopupMenuItem,
    Text,
    colors,
    icons,
)

def main(page):
    def add_clicked(e):
        page.add(Checkbox(label=new_task.value))

    new_task = TextField(hint_text="Whats needs to be done?", width=300)
    page.add(Row([new_task, ElevatedButton("Add", on_click=add_clicked)]))
    t = Text(
    value="This is a Text control sample",
    size=30,
    color="white",
    bgcolor="pink",
    weight="bold",
    italic=True,)
    page.add(t)
    btn = ElevatedButton("Click me!")
    page.add(btn)
    page.scroll='always'
    page.update()
    first_name = TextField()
    last_name = TextField()
    page.add(first_name, last_name)
    sleep(2)
    first_name.disabled = True
    last_name.disabled = True
    page.update()
    first_name = TextField()
    last_name = TextField()
    c = Column(controls=[
        first_name,
        last_name
        ])
    c.disabled = True
    page.add(c)
    flet.app(target=main2)

def main2(page: Page):
    def check_item_clicked(e):
        e.control.checked = not e.control.checked
        page.update()

    page.appbar = AppBar(
        leading=Icon(icons.PALETTE),
        leading_width=40,
        title=Text("AppBar Example"),
        center_title=False,
        bgcolor=colors.SURFACE_VARIANT,
        actions=[
            IconButton(icons.WB_SUNNY_OUTLINED),
            IconButton(icons.FILTER_3),
            PopupMenuButton(
                items=[
                    PopupMenuItem(text="Item 1"),
                    PopupMenuItem(),  # divider
                    PopupMenuItem(
                        text="Checked item", checked=False, on_click=check_item_clicked
                    ),
                ]
            ),
        ],
    )
    page.add(Text("Body!"))

















#flet.app(target=main, view=flet.WEB_BROWSER)
flet.app(target=main)

"""
import flet
from flet import IconButton, Page, Row, TextField, icons

def main(page: Page):
    page.title = "Flet counter example"
    page.vertical_alignment = "center"

    txt_number = TextField(value="0", text_align="right", width=100)

    def minus_click(e):
        txt_number.value = int(txt_number.value) - 1
        page.update()

    def plus_click(e):
        txt_number.value = int(txt_number.value) + 1
        page.update()

    page.add(
        Row(
            [
                IconButton(icons.REMOVE, on_click=minus_click),
                txt_number,
                IconButton(icons.ADD, on_click=plus_click),
            ],
            alignment="center",
        )
    )

flet.app(target=main)
"""


"""
#                                                                   Navigation Bar

import flet
from flet import (
    Column,
    FloatingActionButton,
    Icon,
    NavigationRail,
    NavigationRailDestination,
    Page,
    Row,
    Text,
    VerticalDivider,
    icons,
)

def main(page: Page):

    rail = NavigationRail(
        selected_index=0,
        label_type="all",
        # extended=True,
        min_width=100,
        min_extended_width=400,
        leading=FloatingActionButton(icon=icons.CREATE, text="Add"),
        group_alignment=-0.9,
        destinations=[
            NavigationRailDestination(
                icon=icons.FAVORITE_BORDER, selected_icon=icons.FAVORITE, label="First"
            ),
            NavigationRailDestination(
                icon_content=Icon(icons.BOOKMARK_BORDER),
                selected_icon_content=Icon(icons.BOOKMARK),
                label="Second",
            ),
            NavigationRailDestination(
                icon=icons.SETTINGS_OUTLINED,
                selected_icon_content=Icon(icons.SETTINGS),
                label_content=Text("Settings"),
            ),
        ],
        on_change=lambda e: print("Selected destination:", e.control.selected_index),
    )

    page.add(
        Row(
            [
                rail,
                VerticalDivider(width=1),
                Column([Text("Body!")], alignment="start", expand=True),
            ],
            expand=True,
        )
    )

flet.app(target=main)


"""


"""

#                                                                   Appbar




import flet
from flet import (
    AppBar,
    Icon,
    IconButton,
    Page,
    PopupMenuButton,
    PopupMenuItem,
    Text,
    colors,
    icons,
)

def main(page: Page):
    def check_item_clicked(e):
        e.control.checked = not e.control.checked
        page.update()

    page.appbar = AppBar(
        leading=Icon(icons.PALETTE),
        leading_width=40,
        title=Text("AppBar Example"),
        center_title=False,
        bgcolor=colors.SURFACE_VARIANT,
        actions=[
            IconButton(icons.WB_SUNNY_OUTLINED),
            IconButton(icons.FILTER_3),
            PopupMenuButton(
                items=[
                    PopupMenuItem(text="Item 1"),
                    PopupMenuItem(),  # divider
                    PopupMenuItem(
                        text="Checked item", checked=False, on_click=check_item_clicked
                    ),
                ]
            ),
        ],
    )
    page.add(Text("Body!"))

flet.app(target=main)


"""
```

Answer (score 1):

Flet didn't have the routes feature when I posted this, the developer of flet says, it's going to roll out in a week.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIFFM.png)

Answer (score 1):

Please check the [Navigation and routing](https://flet.dev/docs/guides/python/navigation-and-routing) docs of flet.
There is already routing in python flet, example your modified app:

```
import flet
from flet import Checkbox, ElevatedButton, Row,Text, TextField, Column
from flet import (
    AppBar,
    Icon,
    IconButton,
    Page,
    PopupMenuButton,
    PopupMenuItem,Text,
    colors,
    icons,
    View
)

def main(page: Page):
    page.scroll='always'
    
    def change_route(route):
        
        new_task = TextField(hint_text="Whats needs to be done?", width=300)
        first_name = TextField(disabled=True)
        last_name = TextField(disabled=True)
        first_name.disabled = True
        last_name.disabled = True
        
        c = Column(
            controls=[
                first_name,
                last_name,
            ],
            disabled=True,
        )
        
        t = Text(
            value="This is a Text control sample",
            size=30,
            color="white",
            bgcolor="pink",
            weight="bold",
            italic=True,)
        
            
        def add_clicked(e):
            page.add(Checkbox(label=new_task.value))
            
        def check_item_clicked(e):
            e.control.checked = not e.control.checked
            page.update()
        
        page.views.clear()  # CLEAR THE VIEWS
        page.views.append(  # BUILD THE VIEW 1
            View(
                route='/',
                controls=[
                    AppBar(
                        title=Text(f"Main route ({page.route})"),
                        bgcolor=colors.SURFACE_VARIANT
                    ),
                    ElevatedButton("Go to another view", on_click=lambda _: page.go("/another_view")),
                    t,
                    c,
                    Row([new_task, ElevatedButton("Add", on_click=add_clicked)])
                    
                ]
            )
        )
        if page.route == "/another_view":
            page.views.append(  # BUILD THE VIEW 2
                View(
                    route='/another_view',
                    controls=[
                        AppBar(
                            title=Text(f"Other view ({page.route})"),
                            leading=Icon(icons.PALETTE),
                            leading_width=40,
                            center_title=False,
                            bgcolor=colors.SURFACE_VARIANT,
                            actions=[
                                IconButton(icons.WB_SUNNY_OUTLINED),
                                IconButton(icons.FILTER_3),
                                PopupMenuButton(
                                    items=[
                                        PopupMenuItem(text="Item 1"),
                                        PopupMenuItem(),  # divider
                                        PopupMenuItem(
                                            text="Checked item", checked=False, on_click=check_item_clicked
                                        ),
                                    ]
                                ),
                            ]
                        ),
                        ElevatedButton("Go to main view", on_click=lambda _: page.go("/")),
                        Text("Body!")
                    ]
                )
            )

        page.update()
        
    page.on_route_change = change_route
    page.go(page.route)

flet.app(target=main)
```